# Google crawler login in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, csrf-protection, google-crawlers

I have an app with Devise users and am trying to allow a google crawler to be able to login, so I can add ads in my newsfeed page, which is restricted to signed in users only (because the content is purely dynamic and has to do with each users followers).

1. How do I add a csrf token for the crawler login? Error: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity.
2. Sessions controller has the `require(:user)` part which means the parameters should be user[email] and user[password], but the respective fields in the crawler login settings, don't allow such characters: "[" and "]"

I wasn't able to find any rails related answers, which seems weird. Am I missing something? Are there other techniques to achieve this?

Comment: I think what you are doing might be classified as cloaking by Google and may cause you problems. More details here [link](https://support.google.com/news/publisher/answer/40543?hl=en)

Comment: @brod Thanks for the input! Based on the video and explanation in the link your provided and more specifically [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66355), yes having a newsfeed that is customized for each user (and thus googlebot as well) could be considered as cloaking. My adsense was suspended before so I guess that could be one of the major reasons, so I will leave this out of our campaigns for the time being. However if I want to add ads to other pages restricted to logged in users only in the future, the problem is still the same, so I'll leave this open for more answers.